# how to free memory from mx.ndarray

Tags: mxnet

I write a custom op in Python layer. implemented with operators of `mx.nd.op_name`, It work normal when the shape of input is in the same. But it tells out of memory when its' shape is different.the custom op as below. It seems like the memory of `self.output` haven't be free when forward function is done. and i try to `del self.output`, but it don't work. can you provided some suggestions?

```py
def forward(...):
    self.output = mx.nd.op_name(inputs)
    do others

def backward(...):
   do backward
```